# Link within a bootstrap list-group-item, but popup confirmation before clicking link

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, popupwindow

I have a 'bootstrap list group item'. I am trying to create a link **inside the link area**. The code below works:

```
// THIS CODE WORKS //

<a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active text-white rounded-0">

              // --- JUST A BUNCH OF HTML COMES HERE -- //

<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="window.open('?delete=<?=$x?>','_self');return false;"></i>


</a>
```

Now what I would like to do is to add a confirmation to this so the user doesn't delete by mistake.

```
// WANT TO ADD THIS FEATURE //

  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
```

How would I combine these to? When I try they will not execute. I have tried.

```
// WHAT I TRIED //

function Heya()
{
 return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
}

function Hoo()
{
    window.open('?delete','_self');return false;
}


// AND ON THE PAGE //

<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="Heya(); Hoo();"></i>
```

It doesn't work... And I also need a way to pass on the variable 'x' to the script since it will differ..

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkDelete(x)
{
 if (confirm('Are you sure you want to archive?')) {
   var url = '?delete=' + x;
   window.open(url,'_self');
 }
  return false;
}

<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="return checkDelete(<?=x?>);"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but for some reason it will not execute the script but it only continues to load the fist href="" link that is listed where the class="list-group-item" is located.. I think the problem is because the onclick is inbetween a set of <a> </a>...

Comment: @MarcusSilverman I forgot to return false, which negates the propagation. I revised my answer

Comment: Thanks again @John Tyner, but unfortunately same problem, even with the revised version. For some reason the script will not execute.. I even tried other browsers thinking it could maybe be a browser issue..

Comment: @MarcusSilverman - My local tests with your exact code work. Just for tests, you might try removing the classes from the surrounding anchor tag just in case there is some conflict with those. I also wonder if you don't have some broken or malformed HTML tags in there which could cause trouble

Comment: Thanks @John Tyner, I appreciate it. I just tried removing the surrounding anchors.. but still same problem. Will try and troubleshoot more. The strange thing is, if I put my old code back onclick="window.open('?delete=<?=$x?>','_self');return false;" it still works..

Comment: Got it working! Not sure what I changed but now it works! Thanks a million!